# How do I make this checkbox be before my h3 element?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have this HTML and CSS markup:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

._contain_items {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

._inline_task {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

._when {
  margin-top: 0% !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0% !important;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

._lightweighted {
  margin-top: 0% !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #7f8ca1;
}

._title_task {
  margin-top: 0% !important;
  margin-bottom: 0% !important;
}

.checkbox-container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox-container label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.checkbox-container label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="_contain_items">
  <h3> Employee Tasks </h3>
  <hr style="border: none;height: 1px;background-color: #333;">

  <div class="_inline_task">

    <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
      <label for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>

    <h3 class="_title_task"> Title of the task </h3>
    <h3 class="_when"> Tomorrow </h3>

  </div>

  <p class="_lightweighted"> Housekeeping </p>

</div>

</body>
```

The problem that I'm facing is at the checkbox. I want to make a circle checkbox with this ✔️ sign. When `position` is `absolute` it works as intended but it is not before `h3`(Title of the task). When I change `position` at `relative` the circle appears at the right place but the sign its not there. How do I make it appear before the `h3`?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<h3>` tag inside the `<label>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some accessibility issues, so here are my recommendations:

- Avoiding too many `h3` that could be replaced by a `span` or `p`.
- Put the text related to the checkbox inside the `label`. [Also is not a good practice to put a heading inside the `label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#headings)
- [Use `rem` instead `px` for `font-size`, due to `px` won't resize with the user preferences.](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/surprising-truth-about-pixels-and-accessibility/#accessibility-considerations-5)

So here is your code with my considerations

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked/>
  <label for="checkbox">
    <span class="title-task">Title of the task</span>
    <span class="when">Tomorrow</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

and the checkbox css with this:

```
.checkbox>label {
  position: relative; /* Create a positioning context */
  /* ... */
}
.checkbox>label:before {
  /* checkbox styling */
  /* ... */
}
.checkbox>input {
  /* hide the checkbox */
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
.checkbox>input:checked+label:before {
  /* checkbox checked styling */
  /* ... */
}
.checkbox>input+label:after {
  /* checkbox checked icon */
  position: absolute; /* Position the checkmark */
  /* ... */
}
.checkbox>input:checked+label:after {
  /* ... */
}
```

Here I left you a full-functioning snippet with your modified code

```css
.contain-items {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100%;
}

.divider {
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
}

.inline-task {
  display: flex;
  /* row by default */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 100%;
}

.checkbox>label {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox>label:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 1.75rem;
}

.checkbox>input {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.checkbox>input:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.checkbox>input+label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.checkbox>input:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lightweighted {
  color: #7f8ca1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contain-items">
    <h3>Employee Tasks</h3>
    <hr class="divider" />
    <article class="inline-task">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked/>
        <label for="checkbox">
          <span class="title-task">Title of the task</span>
          <span class="when">Tomorrow</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <p class="lightweighted">Housekeeping</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, front end is not my strong suit and sometimes I struggle a bit with these things. It was really nice of you suggesting what I need to watch over next time. Kudos!!